# Folding interleaved tables into single table

Tags: pandas

Let's say you have a `data.tsv` file that contains three types of rows

```
path    lib/app/app_config.dart

commit  8a6461f 2022-04-02 20:59:02 -0400   add separate settings (#7)
3   0   app_config.dart

commit  d27d268 2022-04-02 20:06:48 -0400   update recommended style (#6)
15  4   app_config.dart
```

And you want to combine this data into a clean table like this

```
path                    commit   ts                        message                        additions deletions
lib/app/app_config.dart 8a6461f  2022-04-02 20:59:02 -0400 add separate settings (#7)     3         0
lib/app/app_config.dart d27d268  2022-04-02 20:06:48 -0400 update recommended style (#6)  15        4
```

Is there a recommended method for performing this transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is recommended or not but it is the approach I would take.  Create new columns by extracting data from the source columns.  Then `ffill()` all but `additions` and `deletions`.  Then delete `NA`.

```
Assuming that the tabs are where the commas are: 

path,lib/app/app_config.dart,,

commit,8a6461f,2022-04-02 20:59:02 -0400,add separate settings (#7)
3,0,app_config.dart,

commit,d27d268,2022-04-02 20:06:48 -0400,update recommended style (#6)
15,4,app_config.dart,
```

Then:

```
df['path'] = df[df[0]=='path'][1]
df['commit'] = df[df[0]=='commit'][1]
df['ts'] = df[df[0]=='commit'][2]
df['comment'] = df[df[0]=='commit'][3]
df['additions'] = df[df[0].str.isnumeric()][0].astype(int)
df['deletions'] = df[df[0].str.isnumeric()][1].astype(int)

df['path'] = df['path'].ffill()
df['commit'] = df['commit'].ffill()
df['ts'] = df['ts'].ffill()
df['comment'] = df['comment'].ffill()

df[['path', 'commit', 'ts', 'comment', 'additions', 'deletions']].dropna()
```

Note there are only two lines in this DataFrame.  Just split display for lack of space.

```
                      path   commit                         ts  \
2  lib/app/app_config.dart  8a6461f  2022-04-02 20:59:02 -0400   
4  lib/app/app_config.dart  d27d268  2022-04-02 20:06:48 -0400   

                         comment  additions  deletions  
2     add separate settings (#7)        3.0        0.0  
4  update recommended style (#6)       15.0        4.0
```